# What does the phrase "make up the cash" mean?

Tags: phrases, expressions

"A puts M as apprentice to B, and gives a guarantee to B for M's fidelity. B promises on his part that he will, at least once a month, see M *make up the cash*. B omits to see this done as promised, and M embezzles. A is not liable to B on his guarantee."

In the above example. what exactly does "make up the cash" mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Making up the cash](http://www.slideshare.net/mohamedabdouetman/igcse-accounting-0452-draft-theoritical)** is an accounting term for reconciling the receipts for money spent from a float such as petty cash with the amount remaining, when using the [imprest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imprest_system) system of accounting.

That might typically be done monthly. In this case B didn't bother to do the reconciliation, and presumably the float was maintained by issuing company cheques, so that M was able to embezzle funds over some period of time (greater than one month) without being detected.

Although it's understandable from context, I don't think it's a very common term.

Comment: This is an interesting explanation, but is the expression used to mean 'reconcile receipts with cash' or are you assuming it? https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=make+up+the+cash&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmake%20up%20the%20cash%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Josh61  The responsible person is supposed to replentish the cash to the imprest amount (according to the reference I linked) and presumably they would examine receipts at that time to make sure that the spending within the previous month was legitimate.

Answer (score 0):

Make up the cash here means "handling of accounts to register correct entries" as I understand the phrase.

Comment: Please use a spell checker at this site.

Answer (score 0):

this example is a situation in Contract of Guarantee wherein the Creditors act or omission impairs surety's eventual remedy.. in Contract Laws

Comment: I haven't got a clue what you're saying. Would you mind expanding your answer for the benefit of this lay person? Thank you.

Comment: The example is from a law book but the legal implication was not what I was looking for. the phrase making up the cash has been explained already.